# Java space and newline regex for split

Tags: java, android, regex

for this below method i can find `http://` and `www` into text and i can create html link from that, but in this method i can only split text with `\n` and i want to split with `\n` with space, how to use regex for this action?

```
public static Spanned Htmlparser(String text) {
        String[] tokens = text.split("\n");
        StringBuilder sbStr = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            if ((tokens[i]).contains("www.")) {
                String link = " <a href=\"http://" + tokens[i] + "\">" + tokens[i] + "</a> ";
                sbStr.append(link);
            } else if ((tokens[i]).contains("http://")) {
                String link = " <a href=\"" + tokens[i] + "\">" + tokens[i] + "</a> ";
                sbStr.append(link);
            } else {
                sbStr.append(tokens[i] + " ");
            }
        }
        return Html.fromHtml(sbStr.toString());
    }
```

Java or android have any class for do this action without using my method?

Comment: an example with expected output would be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to split a string by newline \n and space \s characters, you can use character class in regular expressions. See the following code.

```
 String[] tokens = text.split("[\\n\\s]");
```